# Some tests fails with gradle test command (Spring Boot 3)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, testing, junit5, java-17

My environment is Spring Boot 3.0.2, Gradle and Java 17. I implemented an application with more than 300 unit and integration tests.

After 200 tests my suite became unstable. If I launch the tests from intellij they all work correctly. If I run the tests one by one from the gradle command they also work fine. But if I run all the tests together, some randomly fail.

The error is that it fails to load certain mockbeans.

If I put this configuration in the build.gradle then all the tests go well, but it takes a long time.

```
tasks.named('test') {
    forkEvery = 1
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

If I put this other configuration, then other tests fail

```
tasks.named('test') {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Could it be a memory problem? parallel processes or something similar? It is very strange, the truth that does not give me any confidence.

For example, a test class.

```
package ...
import ...

@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class OfferCreateTest {

    @Autowired
    PropertyCreate propertyCreate;

    @Autowired
    OfferCreate offerCreate;

    @MockBean
    ObHttpClient obHttpClient;

    @MockBean
    RoomtypeFind roomtypeFind;

    @MockBean
    RateplanFind rateplanFind;

    @MockBean
    PropertyChannelFind propertyChannelFind;

    private Long propertyId;

    @BeforeAll
    void setup(){
        propertyId = createProperty();
    }

    private Long createProperty(){
        PropertyCreateDto propertyCreateDto = PropertyCreateDtoMother.randomWithFullData();
        return propertyCreate.create(propertyCreateDto).getResult().get("id");
    }

    @Test
    void create_offer(){

        OfferCreateDto offerCreateDto = OfferCreateDtoMother.random();
        Long offerId = offerCreate.create(propertyId, offerCreateDto).getResult().get("id");
        assertTrue(offerId >= 100000L);
    }

    @Test
    void create_offer_on_non_existing_property(){

        OfferCreateDto offerCreateDto = OfferCreateDtoMother.random();
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> offerCreate.create(ContentGenerator.customIdLower(), offerCreateDto));
    }


}
```

Very thanks,

Comment: maik any updates on the topic? I am facing very similar issue... In my case the test fail only in the CI/CD pipelines

Comment: @Klapsa2503 Sorry, I couldn't solve the problem. I stopped implementing tests because they were not stable. I'll try again in a few weeks... If you find something, please tell me.

Comment: Same with Spring Boot 2.7.10, OpenJDK 19.0.1 and Gradle 8.3 locally as well as in CI - I guess it is more related to Gradle, because we are on this Spring version for a while now. But it seems really random. The most failing test is a small custom cache based on a LinkedHashMap that is feeded with a single item and then checked against with containsKey. The others are related to failing to load the Spring ApplicationContext. Which Gradle version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was due to improper usage of `MockStatic`.
If you use `MockStatic` and do not release the resources, the mock object is used when another class is tested.

Therefore, depending on the order of tests, they either succeeded or failed.

Previous code:

```java
mockStatic(UserFactory.class))
    .when(() -> UserFactory.of(anyString(), anyMap()))
    .thenReturn(User.builder().build());
        
when(userRepositoryOAuth2UserHandler.apply(any())).thenReturn(User.builder().build());
when(jwtProvider.createAccessToken(any())).thenReturn("accessToken");
when(jwtProvider.createRefreshToken(any())).thenReturn("refreshToken");

oAuth2LoginSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response,
    createAuthentication());

assertAll(
    () -> assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(SC_OK),
    () -> assertThat(response.getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),
    () -> verify(objectMapper).writeValue(eq(response.getOutputStream()),
              any(LoginSuccessResponse.class))
);
```

Modified code:

```java
try (MockedStatic<UserFactory> mockUserFactory = mockStatic(UserFactory.class)) {
    mockUserFactory
        .when(() -> UserFactory.of(anyString(), anyMap()))
        .thenReturn(User.builder().build());

    when(userRepositoryOAuth2UserHandler.apply(any())).thenReturn(User.builder().build());
    when(jwtProvider.createAccessToken(any())).thenReturn("accessToken");
    when(jwtProvider.createRefreshToken(any())).thenReturn("refreshToken");

    oAuth2LoginSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response,
        createAuthentication());

    assertAll(
        () -> assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(SC_OK),
        () -> assertThat(response.getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),
        () -> verify(objectMapper).writeValue(eq(response.getOutputStream()),
              any(LoginSuccessResponse.class))
    );
}
```

By making these modifications, I was able to solve the problem.